# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in /var/www/html/index.php on line 14

Tags: php

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in /var/www/html/index.php on line 14

```
<?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    include 'header.php';
    include 'dbh.php';

?>

<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
    {
        echo "you are logged in<br>";

        if (isset($_SESSION['active']==0))
            echo "your account is not activated<br>";
        else
            echo "you are logged in and activated<br>";
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
    {
        echo "you are not logged in<br>";
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

i'm relatively new to php and i'm having a problem with my code, i want to make sure that if active in my database is set to 0 then it will echo that they aren't activated. if you see anymore mistakes in my code then please let me know.

thanks

Comment: You have `isset($_SESSION['active']==0)`. The `$_SESSION['active']==0` is an expression which means you are comparing it to something. That isn't allowed as isset is supposed to just check if a variable exists. You would probably want to do something more like `if(isset($_SESSION['active']) && $_SESSION['active'] == 0){` which breaks that if statement up into two expressions, both of which need to be true, the variable needs to be set and needs to equal 0.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn thanks for your fast reply! i realise now that i was using isset incorrectly. your solution works very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['active']==0))
```

Is wrong, because the argument is an expression.

```
if (intval($_SESSION['active']) == 0)
```

Parses to integer and compares it to 0: secure & short

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!empty()` instead of `!isset()`
Example:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['id'])) 
    {
        echo "you are logged in<br>";
    }
else {
//do whatever you want
}
```